# Undefined index from POST form to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a small issue that is frustrating me a bit.

In my request that I am posting, I have the following fields, of which there are multiple rows of:

```
<input type="text" name="invoiceables[{{$id}}][id]">
<input type="text" name="invoiceables[{{$id}}][amount]">
<input type="text" name="invoiceables[{{$id}}][notes]">
```

And if I pull up the exception, this is how it looks as an example return:

```
invoiceables (array (2)):
-- 3127 (array(3):
---"id" => "3127"
---"amount" => "15.00"
---"notes" => "test1"

-- 3082 (array(3):
---"id" => "3082"
---"amount" => "25.00"
---"notes" => "test2"
```

But when I go to use the following in my controller, I get a "Undefined Index: amount" error:

```
foreach($request->invoiceables['amount'] as $key => $val){
    $manifest = Carrier_Manifest::findOrFail($key);
    $manifest->invoices()->save($invoice,['amount'=>$request->invoiceables['amount'][$key],'notes'=>$request->invoiceables['notes'][$key]]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is:

```
$_POST['invoiceables']['SOME ID']['amount']
```

You are ignoring the `'SOME ID'` part and trying to read the amount directly from the invoiceables.

You have **multiple** invoiceables, **each** of which has an amount.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the array dimensions incorrectly. In your loop, $key becomes the ID, and $val is an array of the invoiceable data. Try this:

```
foreach($request->invoiceables as $key => $val){
    $manifest = Carrier_Manifest::findOrFail($key);
    $manifest->invoices()->save($invoice,['amount'=>$val['amount'],'notes'=>$val['notes']]);
    }
```

Comment: I should also note that in my answer I have removed the ['amount'] accessor from the loop array, as that would indicate and array of amounts, whereas you want to access the data as an array of invoiceables.

Answer (score 1):

You array its:
$invoiceables[id][amount]

but you access it like:
$invoiceables[amount][id]